# Is there a url parameter to make Google Custom Search Engine load to a refinement by default?

Tags: google-api, google-custom-search

Is there a `url parameter` that I can add to the search string to trigger Google Custom Search to load to a certain refinement?

I can easily add it to a `<div>`, like this:
`<div class="gcse-search" data-filter="1" data-defaultToRefinement="books">`

However, I am trying to append the search query with something like this:

`<a href="https://coptic-treasures.com/search/?q=query-term" data-defaultToRefinement="books">search</a>` but it didn't work.

I also tried to implement a `javascript` code, but did not work too:

```
<a href="https://example.com/search/?q=query-term">search</a>


<script type="text/javascript">
var customSearchOptions =
    { 'defaultToRefinement' : 'books' };

  var customSearchControl =
    new google.search.CustomSearchControl('006512144780767394578:o0aygtb9h5w', customSearchOptions);

</script>
```

All trials lead to loading the search results in the default search page without triggering the required refinement.

Can someone help me please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a string in the advanced settings to be added to every query.
So, add this - *more:p:*, followed by your refinement name, and it will always be executed.